# FxCop SupressMessage doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop

This is the code where I become `CA1008`from FxCop:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1008:EnumsShouldHaveZeroValue", Justification = "some text..")]
public enum ECommunicationsProfil
{
   Information = 1,
   ...
}
```

Any ideas why `SupressMessage` doesnt work here?

I have `Visual Studio 2012`, `FxCop 10` and `CODE_ANALYSIS` flag on project build.

Comment: Works on my machine™.  Just in case, don't confuse it with CA1704, "Identifiers should be spelled correctly".  At least in English, Profil has an e and Hungarian is no longer in style.

Comment: I have found the problem - was me )    I have used CODE_ANALYSIS for Debug but not for Release... And FxCop analysed Release build..

Comment: @HansPassant cool to have the comment from you! ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem - was me )    I have used `CODE_ANALYSIS` for Debug but not for Release... And FcCop analysed Release build..